# How to return distinct nodes based on relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the movie database, I created a self relationship(ACTED_WITH) on the Person node using the Cypher query.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WHERE p2 <> p1
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[r:ACTED_WITH]-(p2)
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN r IS NULL THEN [0] ELSE [] END) |
MERGE (p1)-[:ACTED_WITH]-(p2)  
)
```

I want to return all the actors of the movie (Cloud Atlas) having ACTED_WITH relationship without duplicates?

This is the Cypher Query, I tried

```
MATCH (m)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a1)-[r]-(a2)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m)
WHERE m.title="Cloud Atlas" RETURN a1,a2
```

The query returns Tom Hanks and Hugo Weaving twice (may be due to bidirectional relationship?).

```
"a1","a2"                                
{"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1956}, {"name":"Hugo Weaving","born":1960} 

{"name":"Hugo Weaving","born":1960}, {"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1956}
```

Expected results

```
"a1", "a2"                                
{"name":"Tom Hanks","born":1956}, {"name":"Hugo Weaving","born":1960}
```

How, can I alter my query so that Tom Hanks and Hugo Weaving is returned only once? Any insight in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try directed relationship between actors: MATCH (m)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a1)-[r]->(a2)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m)
WHERE m.title="Cloud Atlas" RETURN a1,a2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add direction in your query

```
MATCH (m)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a1)-[r]->(a2)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m)
WHERE m.title="Cloud Atlas" RETURN a1, a2
```

It works on my dataset, but it won't work if you have duplicate relationships in both directions.

On other hand, have duplicate relationships seems not good practice, you can read more [here](https://dzone.com/articles/modelling-data-neo4j).

Comment: giving the direction ->(a2) in the query helps. I don't have duplicate any relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Directed and Named** *(In case there are other relationships between persons)* relationship between Actor nodes:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a1:Person)-[r:ACTED_WITH]->(a2:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WHERE m.title="Cloud Atlas" RETURN a1,a2
```

**Suggestion:** Use Label names for better performance and readability